# Converting Adjusted R²

Tags: regression, linear-model, r-squared, linear-algebra, metric

I just examined the $R^2_\text{adj}$ Formula on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination?oldformat=true#Adjusted_R2) and found two ways to calculate the adjusted $R^2$.

Firstly as
$$R^2_\text{adj}=1-\frac{\frac{SS_\text{res}}{(n-p-1)}}{\frac{SS_\text{tot}}{(n-1)}}$$
And secondly as
$$R^2_\text{adj}=1-(1-R^2)\cdot\frac{n-1}{n-p-1}$$
Where $n$ is the number of observations and $p$ the number of variables used in the model.

I tried to obtain the second form of the $R^2_\text{adj}$ by converting the first version of the formula as follows:

Step 1: Reciprocal Multiplication of the Fraction as
$$R^2_\text{adj}=1-\frac{SS_\text{res}}{(n-p-1)}\cdot\frac{(n-1)}{SS_\text{tot}}$$
Step 2: Rearrange the Factors with the Commultative Law as
$$R^2_\text{adj}=1-\frac{SS_\text{res}}{SS_\text{tot}}\cdot\frac{(n-1)}{(n-p-1)}$$
As $R^2$ is defined as $R^2=1-\frac{SS_\text{res}}{SS_\text{tot}}$ it could be inserted into the formula at Step 2 as
$$R^2_\text{adj}=R^2\cdot\frac{(n-1)}{(n-p-1)}$$
but this seems to be incorrect according to the formulation in the textbooks and on the [Wikipedia Section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination?oldformat=true#Adjusted_R2).
I think I am making a fundamental algebraic mistake but it is unclear to me at what point I am doing so, where does my mistake happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's focus on Step 2, where you have

$$R^2_\text{adj}=1-\frac{SS_\text{res}}{SS_\text{tot}}\cdot\frac{(n-1)}{(n-p-1)}$$

As you have mentioned, $R^2=1-\frac{SS_\text{res}}{SS_\text{tot}}$. We want to insert $R^2$ in the expression above. Solving for $\frac{SS_\text{res}}{SS_\text{tot}}$ in the definition you have given for $R^2$, we have

$$ \frac{SS_\text{res}}{SS_\text{tot}}= 1- R^2.$$

Substituting this expression we have

$$R^2_\text{adj}=1-\frac{SS_\text{res}}{SS_\text{tot}}\cdot\frac{(n-1)}{(n-p-1)}= 1-(1-R^2)\cdot\frac{(n-1)}{(n-p-1)}.$$

Your mistake was in not substituting properly $\frac{SS_\text{res}}{SS_\text{tot}}$, but you basically had it. Hope it helps.